# dask-ssh hostfile specify ports

Tags: dask

The [dask-ssh](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/ssh.html) docs say that I can specify a hostfile.  Great.  However, my hosts have ssh running on various different ports, and the docs do not detail a way that I can specify the ssh port number.  How do I specify the ssh port in the dask-ssh hostfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported as of Dask 2.3.

You might want to raise an issue though https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new